# Python Pandas - merge multiple spreadsheets that contains multiple sheets to a single MasterSpreadsheet having all the sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to acomplish something that seems to be very simple using Pandas, but getting stuck.
I want to merge multiple spreadsheets (that have multiple sheets) to one single MasterSpreadSheet with all the sheets.

```
input example:
spreadsheet1 -> sheetname_a, sheetname_b, sheetname_c, sheetname_d
spreadsheet2 -> sheetname_a, sheetname_b, sheetname_c, sheetname_d
spreadsheet3 ......

output desired:
one single file with the data from all spreadsheets separated by the especific sheetname
MasterSpreadSheet -> sheetname_a, sheetname_b, sheetname_c, sheetname_d
```

Here is my code that generates that single MasterSpreadSheet, but it overrides the previous spreadsheet data, leaving the MasterFile with only data from the last spreadsheet:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(outputfolder + '/' + country + '-MasterSheet.xlsx') as writer:

    for spreadsheet in glob.glob(os.path.join(outputfolder, '*-Spreadsheet.xlsx')):
            sheets = pd.ExcelFile(spreadsheet).sheet_names
            for sheet in sheets:
                df = pd.DataFrame()
                sheetname = sheet.split('-')[-1]
                data = pd.read_excel(spreadsheet, sheet)
                data.index = [basename(spreadsheet)] * len(data)
                df = df.append(data)
                df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = sheetname) 

            writer.save()   
            writer.close()
```

Suggestions ?

Thank you !

Comment: It seems the issue is with Pandas ExcelWriter, https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3441

Answer (score 0):

Got that working now :). Have looped and append first sheet by sheet, followed by the spreadsheet file, have also add the pandas concat at the end of it sheet loop:

```
df1 = []
sheet_list = []
sheet_counter = 0
with pd.ExcelWriter(outputfolder + '/' + country + '-MasterSheet.xlsx') as writer:

    for template in glob.glob( os.path.join(templatefolder, '*.textfsm') ):
        template_name = template.split('\\')[-1].split('.textfsm')[0] 
        sheet_list.append(template_name)  ## List of Sheets per Spreadsheet file

    for sheet in sheet_list: 
        for spreadsheet in glob.glob(os.path.join(outputfolder, '*-Spreadsheet.xlsx')):
            data = pd.read_excel(spreadsheet, sheet_counter)
            data.index = [basename(spreadsheet)] * len(data)
            df1.append(data)
        df1 = pd.concat(df1)    
        df1.to_excel(writer, sheet)
        df1 = []
        sheet_counter += 1  ##Adding a counter to get the next Sheet of each Spreadsheet
```

Comment: Hi I am very new to Python, could you explain how you run this code?